# How does one send .env files to a git submodule during pm2 deployment?

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, git-submodules, pm2

TLDR: How can one send `.env` files to a submodule during the `pm2` deployment process while avoiding the `fatal: destination path '/home/projects/client' already exists and is not an empty directory` error message from `git`?

I'm running an automatic deployment script which clones some .env files from my local machine into my production machine, using pm2.

The below script does the following:

1. Clones the `.env` files from my local machine into the host for both my server and the client
2. Deploys the project w/ `pm2`
3. Is *supposed* to update the submodules***
4. Installs the dependencies for my server and build the server
5. Install the dependencies for my front-end (create-react-app) and builds the frontend
6. Run the project

   ```
   deploy: {
      production: {
        user: "harrison",
        host: hosts,
        key: "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
        ref: "origin/master",
        repo: process.env.GIT_REPO,
        path: process.env.PROJECT_PATH,
        "pre-deploy-local": `./deployEnvs.sh ${process.env.PROJECT_PATH} ${hostsBashArgs} && \
         ./deployClientEnvs.sh ${process.env.PROJECT_PATH} ${hostsBashArgs}`,
        "post-deploy": `source ~/.zshrc && \
         git submodule update --init --recursive && \
         yarn install --ignore-engines && \
         yarn prod:build && \
         cd client && \
         yarn install --ignore-engines && \
         yarn build && \
         cd ../ && \
         yarn prod:serve`,
      },
   ```

*** The problem that I'm having relates to the part of the script that downloads the submodule (everything else works fine).
The script tells me that the client folder is not empty (this is because it's necessary for me to send the `.env` files to the client folder before building the application.

Is it possible for me to somehow send the `.env` files to the client folder ***after*** updating the submodule? How can I send the `.env` files from my local machine to the submodule and avoid the "this directory is not empty" message?

For clarity, here is my folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Copy these env files in another directory on the distant server, then have the post-deploy action get them at the right time (after the submodules are initialized).